Please add total number of flags raised and total number of helpful flags to the flag history
The Impact box on the User Activity page currently shows the total number of helpful flags raised, for example the following image shows 213 helpful flags:

On clicking, we are redirected to the users flag summary page. This total of 213 flags is not currently visible but is made up of helpful post flags, comment flags, and spam flags (and maybe more categories that I am not aware of).
Would it be possible to show the total number of helpful flags raised on the flag summary page and also show some other totals, for example, the total number of flags raised (which as well as helpful flags would include declined and retracted flags and also flags pending review). For example, like this mock up:


Do you know / use this user script: Flagging Assistant - tweaks for frequent flaggers

Moderators see the following (on your profile): "1,572 helpful flags (x)" where x is replaced with the number of unhelpful flags.

@rene I don't use user scripts, so I wasn't aware of that script, but I will investigate that one.

fyi Where can I see the number of flags that were marked as helpful over the past 7 days?
